# create pdf from current page ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, render

I want to create a PDF from my current page on button click. 
Now my Code looks like that:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
     renderPDF = true;
}

protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (renderPDF == true)
        {
            dtAnswer = taAnswer.GetData();
            MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
            StreamWriter twr = new StreamWriter(mem);
            HtmlTextWriter myWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(twr);
            base.Render(myWriter);
            myWriter.Flush();
            myWriter.Dispose();
            StreamReader strmRdr = new StreamReader(mem);
            //strmRdr.BaseStream.Position = 3300;
            //string pageContent = strmRdr.ReadToEnd();
            //strmRdr.Dispose();
            //mem.Dispose();
            //writer.Write(pageContent);

            //CreatePDFDocument(pageContent);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<table border='1' width='100%' style='font-size:11px; font-weight:bold; border-collapse:collapse; font-family: Arial, 'Lucida Sans Unicode', sans-serif; '>");
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            sb.Append("<td style='background-color:red; text-align:center;' colspan ='3'>maxon motor</td>");
            sb.Append("</tr>");
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            sb.Append("<td width='18%'><p>maxon motor ag</p><p>Sachseln</p></td>");
            sb.Append("<td width ='64%' style='text-align:center'><p>Vorstellungsgespräch</p></td>");
            sb.Append("<td width='18%'><p>Seite</p></td>");
            sb.Append("</tr>");
            sb.Append("</table>");

            sb.Append("<br /><br />");
            sb.Append("<Table style=\"width:100%;font-weight:bold;border-collapse:collapse; font-family: Arial, 'Lucida Sans Unicode', sans-serif;\">");
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            sb.Append("<td><p>Name / Vorname:</p></td>");
            sb.Append("<td></td>");
            sb.Append("</tr>");
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            sb.Append("<td><p>Geb. Datum:</p></td>");
            sb.Append("<td></td>");
            sb.Append("</tr>");
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            sb.Append("<td><p>Offene Stelle zugewiesen:</p></td>");
            sb.Append("<td></td>");
            sb.Append("</tr>");
            sb.Append("<tr>");
            sb.Append("<td><p>Gesprächsteilnehmer:</p></td>");
            sb.Append("<td></td>");
            sb.Append("</tr>");
            sb.Append("</table>");
            sb.Append("<br /><br />");

            sb.Append("<div>");
            for (int i = 0; i < pQuestions.Controls.Count; i++)
            {
                string sName = "lbl" + pQuestions.Controls[i].ID.Substring(3, pQuestions.Controls[i].ID.Length - 3);
                if (pQuestions.Controls[i].ID == sName)
                {
                    if (!pQuestions.Controls[i].ID.Contains(","))
                    {
                        string sBlockName = pQuestions.Controls[i].ID.Substring(3, pQuestions.Controls[i].ID.Length - 3);
                        sb.Append("<p><b>" + sBlockName + "</b></p>");
                        sb.Append("<br />");
                        for (int t = 0; t < pQuestions.Controls.Count; t++)
                        {
                            if (pQuestions.Controls[t].ID.Contains(sBlockName))
                            {
                                if (pQuestions.Controls[t].ID.Contains("lbl") && pQuestions.Controls[t].ID != pQuestions.Controls[i].ID)
                                {
                                    sb.Append("<p>" + ((Label)(pQuestions.Controls[t])).Text + "</p>");
                                    sb.Append("<br />");
                                }
                                else if (pQuestions.Controls[t].ID.Contains("txt"))
                                {
                                    if (((TextBox)(pQuestions.Controls[t])).Text != "")
                                    {
                                        sb.Append("<p>" + ((TextBox)(pQuestions.Controls[t])).Text + "</p>");
                                        sb.Append("<br />");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        sb.Append("<br /><br /><br /><br />");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            sb.Append("</div>");

            StringReader sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
            string rr= sb.ToString();
            CreatePDFDocument(rr);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            HtmlTextWriter tw = new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb));
            base.Render(tw);
            // get the captured markup as a string
            string pageSource = tw.ToString();
            //Get the rendered content
            string sContent = sb.ToString();
            //Now output it to the page, if you want
            writer.Write(sContent);
        }
    }

public void CreatePDFDocument(string strHtml)
        {
            string strHTMLpath = "c:\\MyHTML.html";
            StreamWriter strWriter = new StreamWriter(strHTMLpath, false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            strWriter.Write(strHtml);
            strWriter.Close();
            string strFileName = "C:\\map1.pdf";
            // step 1: creation of a document-object
            Document document = new Document();
            // step 2:
            // we create a writer that listens to the document
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Create));
            StringReader se = new StringReader(strHtml);
            TextReader tr = new StreamReader("C:\\MyHTML.html");

            //add the collection to the document
            document.Open();
            HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(document);

            worker.StartDocument();

            //// step 5: parse the html into the document
            worker.Parse(tr);

            //// step 6: close the document and the worker
            worker.EndDocument();

            //worker.Parse(tr); // getting error "Illegal characters in path"
            document.Close();
            ShowPdf(strFileName);
        }

public void ShowPdf(string strFileName)
            {
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + strFileName);
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.WriteFile(strFileName);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.Clear();
            }
```

Now, my problem is, I want to create e pdf from one part of the page and **not** the whole page.
How can i realize that?

Thanks a lot!
Sarah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create string congaing all `Html` that you want to see in `pdf` but css will not be applied through class. For applying `css` you have to write `inline-css` for all DOM elements. You can do so as below

```
            string = "Pdf Contents in html format";
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString());

            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
            HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, memoryStream);
                pdfDoc.Open();
                htmlparser.Parse(sr);
                pdfDoc.Close();
                byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                memoryStream.Close();
           }
```

for more info visit [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Generate-Create-PDF-and-send-as-email-attachment-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Hope this is helpfull

Comment: But how can I set a background color on a table? It doesn't work

Comment: as I mentioned, you have to use inline css everywhere. eg.

<table style="background-color:yellow;">

Comment: sb.Append("<td style='background-color:red; text-align:center;' colspan ='3'>test</td>");

Comment: Is data rendering properly?

Comment: why don't you apply css to table?